# Calling two views in third Django view

Tags: python, django, view

i have a little scraping script which i try transfer to django. My problem is i want call two views (which should return something) in third view but it is not working.
Here are my views:

```
def create_request(url): 
    req = Request( 
        url,
        data=None, 
        headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
        }
    )
    return req 

def get_request(req):
    return urlopen(req).read()

def scraping(request):
    link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query='
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get("textfield")
        data = data.replace(" ", "+")
        if data is None:
            return ''
        else:
            search = link + data + '&x=0&y=0'
            eleven = urllib.urlopen(search)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(
                     get_request(create_request(eleven)),     
                     features="lxml" 
                    ) 

        anchor = soup.find("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})
        my_link = anchor.get("href")
        return render(request, 'scrapingscore.html', my_link)
```

Now my error is:

```
ValueError at /Website/scraping
The view Website.views.scraping didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you're trying to use the Django `Request` object which is what views receive and doesn't actually make any request.  You probably want to install "requests" and do `request.get()`.  (unless I'm totally misunderstanding what you're trying to do)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me explain it a little - 'create_request' function is to show website which i will choose to scrap data that i am not a bot. Then 'get_request' function is a little wrapper for opening and reading any url. I want to use both functions in line with soup variable - firstly creating a request for our url, and then reading it. Lastly passing readed HTML of website as parameter. This script works when i want to open it in python, it just does not work when i am trying to transfer it to Django. At this moment i am getting an error: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is in line where i define soup variable - i added more details of this error to main post at the bottom.

Comment: It looks like the issue is `scraping` doesn't actually return a proper `Response` object so you get an exception in your middleware.

Comment: The problem is the view only returns a non-`None` value on `POST`.  If you try loading it with `GET` you'll get that exception.

Comment: You mean this error 'str' object has no attribute 'get'? I tried to change lines in views.py where was POST, i changed it to GET, also in template. Probably i am doing wrong something because still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried request.POST['textfield'] instead of request.POST.get("textfield")?

Comment: Thank you for your activity, i tried many versions with this line because i also had problem with it - with 'request.POST['textfield']' i got an error 'MultiValueDictKeyError at /Website/scraping
'textfield'' - that's why i used 'request.POST.get("textfield")' which i think works but maybe still it is a reason of next problems.

Comment: try this bor 
if request.method == 'POST':
  data = request.POST.get("textfield")

Comment: Thank you, it looks like you solved this error :) I edited main post with my code. I just would like to display a link (which will be created by this view) to the user on other site. I try to do it with render, but it does not work. I am also concerned that i am using this django view in not good way and it will not work where website 'scraping.html' will appear.

Comment: why render() is not working? can you show your code?

Comment: Of course, i edited first post, here you can see a code - last line is 'return render(request, 'scrapingscore.html', my_link)'

Comment: are you sure your template directory is correct?
other than that in render function take a dict to send data in template

Comment: try redirect it after POST data

Comment: Template directory is good because it works in other views which i created to register user. You mean redirect instead of return?

Comment: yeah. redirect it to other url and then render your template

Comment: I tried to do something like this: return HttpResponseRedirect('scrapingscore') and in next line return render(request, 'scrapingscore.html', my_link) and i tried also do other variations of this solutions, i am not very good in Django but i think there is a problem with calling that two first views in main view 'scraping', maybe better solution will be creating one view from this three?

Comment: try return redirect(your url) and do not return render(request, 'scrapingscore.html', my_link) in next line

Comment: Thank you for your time but my django website still does not work :(